# Allowing Cordova (IOS 13) InAppBrowser through whitelist VPN

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

In my Cordova app, I'm using "cordova.InAppBrowser.open" to load external URL.

On my device, I have a whitelist base VPN (only listed app are allowed through the VPN and get internet access).

My app is whitelisted and can access the internet with no problem.

The problem is that the InAppBrowser can't seem to access the internet although my app is whitelisted.

I assume I need to whitelist in the VPN app something that's got to do with the InAppBrowser but I can't figure out what exactly.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever get a solution @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2924926/%d7%90v%d7%99